# Error: Missing where attribute in the options parameter passed to findOrCreate.

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to use sequelize findOrCreate function, but I'm getting this error:

```
Error: Missing where attribute in the options parameter passed to findOrCreate.
```

This is my code:

```
var values = { slack_id: profile.id, name: profile.user };
var selector = { where: { slack_id: profile.id } };
User.findOrCreate(values, selector)
            .then(function() {
                return done(err, user);
            });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 Missing where attribute in the options parameter passed to 
 findOrCreate. Please note that the API has changed, and is now options 
 only (an object with where, defaults keys, transaction etc.)
```

You should switch the arguments so that the object containing the where clause is first, not second. The second argument is the place for default keys.

```
User.findOrCreate(selector, values)
        .then(function() {
            return done(err, user);
        });
```

Comment: ```User.findOrCreate({ where: { email: profile.emails[0].value } }, { email: profile.emails[0].value, username: profile.displayName, token: token })
            .then(user => {
                console.log(user)
                return user;
            }).catch(error => console.log(error))```